# How to interpret the two lines in the poem?

Tags: reading, comprehension

[image: 'today is night without the darkness' and "the fish and chip lady sings 'love me tender' over the splutter of fat', what do the two lines mean? Really can't understand it. Thank you for your help.]

'today is night without the darkness' and "the fish and chip lady sings 'love me tender' over the splutter of fat', what do the two lines mean? Really can't understand it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might try [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/). Contextual interpretation is typically well received there.

Answer (score 2):

A tropical beach is virtually deserted at night and when it's raining. Thus the poet can compare a beach scene with no people about and where there is a light rain with  grey clouds moving across the sky to a "night without darkness." The literary device employed is [*oxymoron*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/oxymoron?s=t): the chief quality of night, i.e., that it's dark, is negated, forcing the reader to resolve the paradox by thinking of other qualities, such as quietness and lack of human activity.

Your second question deals with two [*cultural allusions*](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110403142544AAzgUyc): 1) to the humble British dish of batter-fried fish and fried potato wedges, the [*onomatopoeia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia)"splutter" referencing the sound made when food containing any moisture is dropped into hot fat, and 2) to the 1956 hit song by Elvis Presley ["Love Me Tender."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckHaTQFKvnY)

Comment: Thank you very much KarlG! Now I totally understand the first question but still stuck on the second question. I know 'fish and chip' is food and 'love me tender' is a  song, but what does it mean 'the fish and chip lady' and 'over the splutter of fat'?  Does it mean when the lady sing the song it seems like cooking fish and chip? but it doesn't make sense :( Can you help me out again?

Comment: No, the woman sings the song as she's frying up the fish and chips.

Comment: 'the woman sings the song as she's frying up the fish and chips' Does the poet want to imply the woman's voice is magnetic and beautiful, like the sound "splutter" when frying up the fish and chips? sorry i am not a native English speaker. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: _Splutter_ is neither magnetic nor beautiful. The whole poem consists of a series of quite everyday impressions culminating in the _bluest, coldest sea_, the superlatives suggesting a transcendence the other images do not have. The woman singing as she fries food is just one impression. It has no greater significance than what it is.

Comment: I've got it. It is just one of the everyday impressions. Thanks KarlG!!!